# Issue in accessing server side encrypted data from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am publishing data to s3 bucket Test, owned by aws account with id 1. In this bucket there are two top level directories, in one of which I did not use any encryption whereas in the other I have published data using server side encryption. I have used aws/s3 for encrypting data. I am publishing using a firehose managed by same account. The folder structure of this bucket is like following:

```
1. Test/data/students/...
2. Test/data/encrypted/students/...
```

I have been testing read access from different account with id 2, I could access and read the data from 1st folder whereas in the second folder access denied exception is coming.

Bucket level policy for s3 bucket Test is as follows:

```
 {
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "rbs-bi-access",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::2:root",
            ]
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::Test",
            "arn:aws:s3:::Test/*"
        ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

I cannot figure out what I am missing here.

Comment: what is exact error ?

Comment: Access denied error is coming as follows:

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>1234</RequestId>
<HostId>
1234
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Can you try moving the AWS KMS key from the old account to the new account or make the key accessible from the old account. ? here is the link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/share-custom-encryption-keys-more-securely-between-accounts-by-using-aws-key-management-service/

Comment: @Prany So you mean I need to add 2 in Add External Account part, right? But here I have used aws/s3 for encryption, where it seems I cannot edit anything.

Comment: but I think you can enable cross account access for the key ?

Comment: I cannot find any way to do that. On that page following message is coming "This master key is used by default if you don't define a master key when you create an encrypted resource in this service. Settings on this key cannot be modified to ensure the availability, durability and security of this key."

Comment: Ok I think I got you now. I think that the default key is used to encrypt your environment variables automatically without needing to enable encryption helpers. -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html